# Import all components Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a lot of components and the import section looks bloated:

```
import {comp1} from './components/comp1/comp1';
import {comp2} from './components/comp2/comp2';
....
```

Is there a way to write generic import? Something like

```
import * from './components/';
```

Comment: I use an intermediate file './components/components' that exports every file in components. I then use: 
import {comp1, comp2} from './components/components';

Comment: Yeah, I know about this trick. Just curious if there is a more elegant solution

Comment: any luck finding a way for it?

Answer (score 8):

You can use import with `*` and use `as` keyword to create a variable to be used in your component. for example:

```
import * as jwt from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';
```

then in your component refer to it as following:

```
// ...
  console.log(jwt.AuthConfig);
```

Comment: This is only for files that export multiple options: 
`export const a: export const b;`

Answer (score 3):

this is what `index.ts` file for.

I usually write a `index.ts` folder in that folder, and put everything you want into index file.

for example:

`path/component/index.ts`

```
export * from './child component 1/index';
export * from './child component 2/index';
export * from './child component 3/index';
export * from './child component 4/index';
export * from './child component 5/index';
...
```

`some/component/*.component.ts`

import * from 'path/component/index'